# Does the feat Pebble Underfoot allow a creature to trip oversized foes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, creature-size, trip

The benefit of the feat **Pebble Underfoot** (which has as its only prerequisite the feat [Improved Trip](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#improvedTrip)) says

> When attempting to trip a creature at least two size categories larger than you, you gain a +4 bonus on opposed trip checks. If you fail to trip the creature, it cannot immediately attempt to trip you. (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 103)

However, the *Player's Handbook* on [Trip](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#trip) says

> You can try to trip an opponent as an unarmed melee attack. You can only trip an opponent who is one size category larger than you, the same size, or smaller. (158)

Is the benefit of the feat Pebble Underfoot tacitly but specifically *allowing* the creature that possesses the feat to trip foes that are two or more size categories larger than it, **or** must the creature find its own way to trip such foes to gain the benefit of the feat? If the latter, what *are* the ways to trip such oversized creatures so that the feat's benefit can be realized?

*Note:* While the *Dragon Compendium Volume 1* has a really nice [errata document](https://paizo.com/download/dragon/compendium/DragonCompendiumVolumeIErrata.pdf) (*Caution:* PDF, and, hey, look at that erratum on the feat Dead Eye!), this feat goes unmentioned. When originally presented, the feat's language *was* slightly different, but the benefit was essentially the same (*Dragon* #279 63) (*Third Edition* and *3.5* have the same size limits for trip.) The feat is mentioned as an appropriate if niche feat in [several](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?262793-Trying-to-build-a-Halfling-tripper) [trip-build](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=12725.0) handbooks, but the limitation regarding the target's size goes unmentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If the DM allows the Dragon Compendium material to be utilized, then the text of the feat would allow the standard rule to be <strike>ignored</strike> broken, under the conditions specified by the feat. There are several feats that expand rules for situations that aren't normally allowed. Pebble Under Foot would be no exception in this regard.